# SeekBar Android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

**How to hide/Show CheckBox,EditText on onProgressChanged of SeekBar.**
   First when Actvity is Created that time Hide a CheckBox,EditText. & when we Changed the Progress of SeekBar Show the CheckBox,EditText

Comment: You Should use **[`SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In `oncreate()` hide your edittext and checkbox.**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

**And In `setOnSeekBarChangeListener's onProgressChanged()` show your checkbox and edittext. show below:-**

```
 seekbarObj.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      

    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     

    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean isUSer) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

       edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add seekBar listener and then do operations as per you need based on the progress value

```
SeekBar sk=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);     
    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        //Change visibility here based on "progress" value

    }       
});
```